# Pythonic way to compress a remote directory using SSH or FTP

Tags: python, ssh, urllib, paramiko, tarfile

I want to backup a remote directory with a lot of files, and because of that, I need to compress it before downloading it. I can access this folder through SSH or FTP. The host is running on Linux.

I have covered the downloading part with `aioftp`. I was using `paramiko` and `tar` Linux command for compressing the directory in the remote host, but instead, I want to use Python modules (from standard library or not) and avoid using Linux commands. Maybe a combination of `paramiko` to open the session, `urllib` to create the remote object and `tarfile` to compress it can make the job, but I haven't found the way.

In the end, I want a `directory-backup.tar.gz` in my localhost.
How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compress the directory using tools *on the server*.

Using local Python code makes no sense. To compress the files locally, you would have to download the uncompressed files, compress them (with your local Python code), and upload the compressed archive, only to download it then again. That defies the purpose of the compression, right?

If you want to use Python code for compression, you would have to run the Python code on the server. Either by uploading the script and executing it on the server or by feeding the code to remote `python` process. I do not see much advantage of doing that over using ready-made `tar` command.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What makes me wonder this it's that `tar` sometimes gives `Content changed` warning that I can not prevent because I can't modify the remote directory conditions, and the returned code is 1 (like a critical error). So I wanted to manage it with a Python module and handle it easier.

Comment: Also, I clarified in the question that I want to make the compression in the remote host and after that download it to localhost, that's the purpose of the backup.

Comment: OK, but even after your edit, I do not have anything to add to my answer. It still stands.